# How to represent hierarchical product catalog [taxonomy] in Javascript with multiple inheritted attributes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

My product catalog is a classic tree hierarchy, with varying levels of sub-grouping. At each level of sub-grouping, products will share attributes of type:value. At the bottom layer of the tree, there will be products that have inheritted all the attributes from the layers above, plus their own unique attributes.

I envisage using two treeviews, one for nodes, one for attributes; to drag attribute type:value pairs to different levels of the produt categories.

I will then use this object tree to search for products that have certain attribute pairs...and display accordingly; as they will have inheritted all attributes?

Can I represent this easily in Javascript by instantiating a sub-class of each level?

Can a similar model be used for hierarchical attributes (type:value)? 
e.g. Manufactuer -> Range -> Series

---

```
Node = function (txt) { this.level = txt; this.child = []; }

var node = new Array();

node[0] = new Node ("root");
// Add first level
node[1] = new Node ("Paper");
node[0].child.push(node[0]);
// Add second level
node[2] = new Node ("Cut Paper");
node[1].child.push(node[2]);
// Add third level
node[3] = new Node ("A4 Paper");
node[2].child.push(node[3]);
// Add fourth level
node[4] = new Node ("ABC12345");
node[3].child.push(node[4]);

node[3]["Length"]="297mm";
node[3]["Width"]="210mm";
node[4]["Weight"]="80gsm";
```

Comment: I started writing out an answer trying to implement both the parent-child node structure and the parent-child inheritance, but ended up coming to the conclusion that you might be best looking at using a library like http://backbonejs.org/ , which has inbuilt support for inheritance and manipulating/traversing collections of objects, although it's not the easiest thing to learn.

Comment: backbonejs may well be the option. Also looking at knockoutjs MVVM so can view changes to node tree. Planning to use inheritance at each node using `if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') { Object.create = function (o) { var F = function () {}; F.prototype = o; return new F(); }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this?

```
    function Node ( text ) {
        this.level = text;
        this.child = {};
        this.parent = false;
    }
    Node.prototype = {
        addChild : function  ( text ) {
            this.child[text] = new Node ( text );
            this.child[text].parent = this;
            return this;
        }
    }
    var root = new Node ("root")
            .addChild("Paper"),
        paper = root.child["Paper"]
            .addChild("Cut Paper"),
        cut_paper = paper.child["Cut Paper"]
            .addChild("A4 Paper"),
        a4_paper = cut_paper.child["A4 Paper"]
            .addChild("ABC12345");
        abc12345 = a4_paper.child["ABC12345"];
        a4_paper.Length = "297mm";
        a4_paper.Width = "210mm";
        abc12345.Weight = "80gsm";
        console.log( root, paper, cut_paper, a4_paper, abc12345);
```

Comment: Thanks for the "step up". I used Crockford's Object.create; and modified Node.prototype in the above to be: `this.child[text] = Object.create(this);` to get inheritance from nodes above. Also `return this.child[text]` so can assign new child 'node' to an array of nodes [0....n] for traversing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked out some ideas for creating a tree structure. May be of use to you, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/WJ4wc/)